# ..NET CORE 2.1 Razor Windows Authentication Profile and Authorization Stored in SQL

Tags: session, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, httpcontext

I'm building a Core 2.1 intranet app with Razor pages that uses Windows Authentication. The users have profiles stored in a Sql database and are linked with the UserPrincipal Guid.
I planned on populating the HttpContext.Session with a few fields that are retrieved with the Sql query. Where would I do this?